# Join several JSONL files into one large file using Python

Tags: python

I have 10 JSONL files, each file has 50,000 entries and they all follow the same structure:

```
{"tracking_code":"28847594","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","package_type_id":10,"transaction_id":168491899,"shipping_label_created":"2018-09-18 11:57:12"}
{"tracking_code":"28847594","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","package_type_id":10,"transaction_id":168491899,"shipping_label_created":"2018-09-18 11:57:12"}
{"tracking_code":"28847594","from_country":"FR","to_country":"FR","package_type_id":10,"transaction_id":168491899,"shipping_label_created":"2018-09-18 11:57:12"}
...
```

I want to join the 10 files to one file using Python.

The desired output would be having 1 JSONL file with all of the entries from the 10 files. Simply adding file one to another.

Comment: If that's the structure, these are JSONL, not JSON. You can just concatenate JSONL files together (with a tool like `cat`, putting the text of one directly after the text of the other) without doing anything else -- that's perhaps the format's biggest advantage over plain JSON.

Comment: Each files just contains a stream of JSON objects. You don't need to do anything JSON-specific; just concatenate the files.

Comment: How would my Python script look like to take 10 files from a directory and concatenate them in to one?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis, ...do you know how to write one file's contents into another? If so, just do that over and over, with the same destination file opened in append mode.

Comment: ...anyhow, "how do I concatenate several files into one" is a different, simpler question, as it can be simplified to not talk about JSON at all.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is concatenate the files; there's no need to decode, or even acknowledge, the JSON objects in each file.

```
from contextlib import ExitStack
from itertools import chain

filenames = ["file1.json", "file2.json", "file3.json", ...]
with ExitStack() as stack, open("file.json") as out:
    files = [stack.enter_context(open(fname)) for fname in filenames]
    for line in chain.from_iterable(files):
        print(line, file=out)
```

The `ExitStack` collects open file handles whose `close` method should be called. `chain.from_iterable` lets you iterate over the open files one after the other.

This is basically a Python re-implementation of the `cat` command, which you could call directly as well:

```
import subprocess

# cat file1.json file2.json file3.json ... > file.json
filenames = ["file1.json", "file2.json", "file3.json", ...]
with open("file.json", "w") as out:
    subprocess.run(['cat'] + filenames, stdout=out)
```